# Referencing the value of a hyperlinked text box

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I'm having some difficulties with this code. I know it's obnoxiously wordy, but every attempt I made to turn some of these form references into variables to save space ended with me having even less functionality than before.

Basically what I've done so far is create a navigation form with several tabs, one to create a ticket, one to resolve/edit a ticket, and one to search the tickets. The search tab is basically a continuous form that updates based on the search criteria I enter. My goal is that when I click on the ticketID for each record, it will take me to the selected record on the Resolve/Edit Ticket page (on that page I have a combo box [called cboGoToRecord] where you can select the record you want).

I have a hyperlink in place that takes the user to the Resolve/Edit page and code that works ONLY when the line I've denoted with four asterisks (for clarity) is replaced with

```
rst.FindFirst "ticketID =" & [some number].
```

When I do that, the results are as expected. If I leave it as it is below, every record looks up the first record (A Debug.print check shows that the value of this field is apparently always 1...) So I guess what I need to figure out is **how do I access the ticketID hyperlink's value so that I can put it on that line and make my code function effectively?** I apologize if this is overly detailed but figured too much was better than not enough.

```
 Private Sub ticketID_Click()

    'Takes user from Search Tickets to Resolve/Edit Issues tab
    DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frmResolveIssues", "frmBrowseTickets.NavigationSubform"

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = Forms!frmBrowseTickets!NavigationSubform.Form.RecordsetClone
    [Forms]![frmBrowseTickets]![NavigationSubform].Form![cboGoToRecord].Value = [Forms]![frmBrowseTickets]![NavigationSubform].Form![ticketID].Value
****rst.FindFirst "ticketID =" & [Forms]![frmBrowseTickets]![NavigationSubform].Form![cboGoToRecord].Value
    Forms!frmBrowseTickets!NavigationSubform.Form.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark

    Debug.Print [Forms]![frmBrowseTickets]![NavigationSubform].Form![ticketID].Value

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
After altering my form to add a separate hyperlink and referencing the static ticketID, I have concluded that everything I thought was true was not. Finding the value of a hyperlink was NOT the problem. The problem is that my ticketID value truly does insist on being one, and I have no clue how to fix that.

Comment: All exclamation marks beyond the first in `[Forms]![frmBrowseTickets]![NavigationSubform].Form![ticketID].Value` should be dots, as far as I know. Not posting it as the answer because I'm unsure it's as simple as that. So `[Forms]![frmBrowseTickets].[NavigationSubform].Form.[ticketID].Value`

Comment: I NEVER use Navigation form because of difficulty referencing forms. Review http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=32053

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: The original syntax is correct. The only dots are before Form and Value.

Comment: @June7 I know, this has been a nightmare to try to reference... that said, it looks nice and figuring out how to make this hyperlink function right is the last step to finishing my project so I'm determined to make it work somehow! I reviewed that link and **think** my syntax used to reference the forms is right...

Comment: I would use dot before reference to control (in this case, cboGoToRecord) and ! (bang) before a field reference. However, I don't think even that will resolve issue. Are cboGoToRecord and ticketID on the same subform?

Answer (score 1):

When this works:

```
Debug.Print [Forms]![frmBrowseTickets]![NavigationSubform].Form![ticketID].Value
```

then also check out:

```
 Debug.Print [Forms]![frmBrowseTickets]![NavigationSubform].Form![cboGoToRecord].Value
```

As June7, I never use the Navigation form. It complicates everything too much.

Comment: Both of them output a value of 1, but I think it's an issue with the value of the ticketID being read correctly. I can't figure out how to make VBA register that I'm clicking on a number "4", not just some hyperlink. It insists on always having a value of 1. Perhaps the solution is just to create another hyperlinked field for opening the record and leaving ticketID as a regular text box...hm..